# Yup Validation for a field which is conditionally rendered based on a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm working with **react-hook-form** and using YUP for front end validations. I have a scenario where I'm receiving a prop from back-end and and based on that prop I register my input field. I want to mark that field as required upon the form submission. But if I don't receive that prop that field should remain optional.

```
const subscriptionSchema = yup.object().shape({
  premium_subscription: yup.bool(),
  comments: yup.string(),
  keep_your_plan: yup.string().required()
)}
```

**premium subscription** key is optional. That should be validated as required once we pass functional component a prop. How can we evaluate this field as optional or required in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using ternary operator and decided on the basis of the prop whether it should be optional or required.

```
premiumSubscription: isRequired ? yup.string().required()
                                : yup.string().notRequired()
```

That solved my problem.